# useBean vs ServletContextListener

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I need to have an object available through the application in my JSP application. The object must be instantiated once and then the same instance should be used for the life of the application.

I am just a beginner at jsp, so I've seen 2 ways to achieve this:

I have a class MyMenu which is a bean - has setters/getters and no argument constructor.

1) Using listener in web.xml I setup a class like this:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's startup.
        MyMenu appmenu = new MyMenu();
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("appmenu", appmenu);

    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Do stuff during webapp's shutdown.
        MyMenu appmenu = (MyMenu)event.getServletContext().getAttribute("appmenu");
        appmenu.clear();
    }

}
```

2) Not using listener using jsp:useBean like this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="menu" class="net.myjsp1.MyMenu"
    scope="application" />
```

Both result in the ${menu} or ${appmenu} object to be available in my jsp pages.

I think 2nd way makes it more clear where the "menu" object came from when you look at the code in the jsp pages.

What is the preffered way and why?

Answer (score 0):

JSP actions like useBean are something from the past, which shouldn't be used anymore. The role of a JSP is to be a view, which generates markup from data prepared by the controller. Creating a menu is not its responsibility. The listener approach should be preferred.